# Fill html textarea with c# webbroser

Tags: c#, html, textarea

I need to fill textarea using webbrowser. I can't use getElementByID as there's no id in textarea, just name, here's textarea code:

```
<textarea name="txt1"></textarea>
```

thanks..

Comment: @DOTNETBEE doesn't look like it's asp.net.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot get elements by ID, you can always iterate elements by tagname

```
foreach (HtmlElement element in webBbrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea"))
{
     // access text area element here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("txt1");
if (elements.length > 0){
    var txt = elements[0];
    if (txt){
        txt.value = "Hi";
    }
}
```